# Function returning Last record

Tags: oracle, plsql

I don't often use ORACLE PL/SQL by the way but i need to understand what if anything in this function created by someone else
in the company before me is wrong as for it is not returning the latest record i've been told. I found out in some other forum issues that they
suggested to use the max(dateColumn) instead of "row_numer = 1" for example but not quite sure how to and where to incorporate that.

-- Knowing that --
We use Oracle version 12,
CustomObjectTypeA is an custom Oracle OBJECT TYPE defined by some old employee not longer in here,
V_OtherView is of Table_Mnd type beeing defined by some old employee not longer in here,
V_ABC_123 is a view created by some old employee not longer in here as well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_TABLE_APPROVED (NUMBER_F_UPD number, NUMBER_F_GET VARcHAR2)
RETURN Table_Mnd
IS
V_OtherView Table_Mnd
BEGIN
SELECT CustomObjectTypeA (FromT.NUMBER_F, 
        FromT.OP_CODE, 
        FromT.CATG_CODE, 
        FromT.CATG_NAME, 
        FromT.CATG_SORT,
        FromT.ORG_CODE,
        FromT.ORG_NAME
        FromT.DATA_ENTRY_VALID, 
        FromT.NUMBER_RECEIVED, 
        FromT.YEAR_1, 
        FromT.YEAR_2)
BULK COLLECT INTO V_OtherView
FROM (SELECT NUMBER_F,
        OP_CODE,
        CATG_CODE,
        CATG_NAME,
        CATG_SORT,
        ORG_CODE,
        ORG_NAME
        DATA_ENTRY_VALID,
        NUMBER_RECEIVED,
        YEAR_1,
        YEAR_2, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BY ORG_CODE ORDER BY NUMBER_RECEIVED DESC, LOAD_DATE DESC) AS ROW_NUMBER
      FROM V_ABC_123
      WHERE NUMBER_F = NUMBER_F_UPD AND DATA_ENTRY_VALID <> 'OnGoing'
     AND LOAD_DATE >= (SELECT sysdate-10 FROM dual)
     AND LOAD_DATE <= (SELECT DISTINCT LOAD_DATE 
               FROM V_ABC_123 
               WHERE NUMBER_RECEIVED = NUMBER_F_GET)) FromT
WHERE FromT.ROW_NUMBER=1;
RETURN V_OtherView;
END F_TABLE_APPROVED;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the actual datatypes are for the following columns: `V_ABC_123.NUMBER_RECEIVED`, `V_ABC_123.LOAD_DATE`.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey and thanks for your reply:                               NUMBER_RECEIVED is of VarChar2 and LOAD_DATE is of TimeStamp (6)

Answer (score 0):

The important bits of the query are:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (select ...,
             ROW_NUMBER()
             OVER (PARTITION BY ORG_CODE
                   ORDER BY NUMBER_RECEIVED DESC,
                   LOAD_DATE DESC) AS ROW_NUMBER
      ...) FromT
WHERE FromT.ROW_NUMBER = 1;
```

The "ROW_NUMBER" column is computed according to the following window clause:

```
PARTITION BY ORG_CODE
ORDER BY NUMBER_RECEIVED DESC, LOAD_DATE DESC
```

Which means that for each `ORG_CODE`, it will sort all the records by `NUMBER_RECEVED,LOAD_DATE` in descending order. Note that if the columns are Oracle `DATE`s, they will only be accurate to the nearest second; so if there are multiple records with date/times in the exact same 1-second interval, this sort order will not be guaranteed unique. The logic of `ROW_NUMBER` will therefore pick one of them arbitrarily (i.e. whichever record happens to be emitted first) and assign it the value "1", and this will be deemed the "latest". Subsequent executions of the same SQL *could* (in theory) return a different record.

The suspicious part is `NUMBER_RECEIVED` which sounds like it's a number, not a date? Sorting by this means that the records with the highest `NUMBER_RECEIVED` will be preferred. Was this intentional?

I'm not sure why the `PARTITION` is there, this would cause the query to return one "latest" record for each value of `ORG_CODE` that it finds. I can only assume this was intentional.

The problem is that the query can only determine the "latest record" as well as it can based on the data provided to it. In this case, it's possible the data is simply not granular enough to be able to decide which record is the actual "latest" record.

Comment: Hello again Jeffrey anyone else able to help, i wanted to ask IF the values in the 2 columns we order on are not unique then even of we ask the row-number = 1 THAT IT IS NOT SURE THAT WE ARE REALLY DEALING with the latest record is that correct ? Thanks.

Comment: Correct. The database itself has no concept of "latest" record - it's all down to the data. That said, using a timestamp with 6 decimal digits of precision will make it pretty close.

Comment: The reason i was asking was because it seems that there is many times the same values both for the column [NUMBER-RECEIVED] and [LoadDate] even though [LoadDate] id of TimeStamp(6). Not to to repeat myself but this means IT will not always (almost surely) work ?

Comment: Better yet, could i simply add columns in the the order by clause ?

Comment: Yes, you could - if it makes sense. I'm still wondering what the partition on org_code is for.

Comment: Actually i'm not quite sure neighter but why the question ?                        Do you see something not logic in using that ?

Comment: I mean even though partition by will segregate sets by org_code the fact that the columns [NUMBER-RECEIVED] and [LoadDate] aren't unique it wouls never guarantee to send the correct last record even with the mention row_number = 1? Am i right or am i still missing some understanding ? Thanks to all for any valuable suggestions or ideas on what the best solution would be in this case.

Comment: How many "latest" records do you expect from this function? The partitioning will probably cause it to return multiple records. I think you may want to go and analyse the requirements for this function properly - without understanding this and the data model you won't be able to get it right.

Comment: I Beleive its     WHERE FromT.ROW_NUMBER = 1;

Comment: You need to understand the partition clause. You will get one row with `row_number=1` for every distinct value in the partitioning clause. So you may get many records with `row_number=1`.

Comment: Thank you so much all your feed-back so far Jeffrey. By the way this function is actually called from within another function named GlobalFunction, amd as mentionned before i've been told that when it calls our F_TABLE_FUNCTION it doesn't allways returned the correct data (last information).   Which clearly never will guarantee us that it will do so because of the following  clause not beeing enough (granularity) to guarantee us we have the latest LOAD_DATE :                                                 ... NUMBER_RECEIVED DESC, LOAD_DATE DESC ...

Comment: In conclusion : What exactly does this WHOLE  function do ? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose a problem when all the info you've been given is a vague "it doesn't always return the correct data".

Comment: I definetely agree with you Jeffrey.       The thing is i wanted to understand at best what this function performed BEFORE changing anything :( in it and start executing the modified code like for example the order by clause if the partition by clause.      As mentionned i don't often code with PL/SQL and when using microsoft sql it is once a month or so as for i use BI tools that creates the sql in the backen but of course i still need to validate the sql code and to code easy to medium difficult queries to confirm what the BI reports display. The original employee no longer works here.

Comment: Well, I could take you through this line-by-line but stackoverflow is not a good format for that kind of thing. The query has some strange-looking logic which was probably built up over time to handle various edge-cases or fix various bugs, and without knowing your data model or requirements it'll be very difficult to tease these out.